# Oracle database rpm package not loading to CentOS using curl command

Tags: oracle, curl, centos7, wget

I have to install oracle database on CentOS 7.0.

As an instruction i use oracle tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/procedure-installing-oracle-database-xe.html

First three steps i passed without any problem. Pre-installed package downloaded and installed successfully.

But as for the main .rpm package, I cannot download it. My download command is similar to pre-installed package:

```
curl -o oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/db-express/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

After the command, I see the following:
[image]

It is worth mentioning that I am doing this in a docker container(https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/). But I also tried to do it locally and the result was similar.

I would be grateful for any help in answering the question why the .rpm package is not downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wget** command solved the problem:

```
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/db-express/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

curl with -v flag showed that it *cannot resolve host*.

The reason was that **curl does not resolve the 302 response**, but wget does.